# intercepting [HTMLElement].innerHTML modifications in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a function called x(). I want to call x() every time an arbitrary node's innerHTML property is being changed (please note that I want x() to be called for all nodes, not just 1 node). Initially, I thought innerHTML was a function of the HTMLElement object, and wanted to monkey patch it, but after playing around in Chrome's Javascript console, I failed to find the innerHTML function in the HTMLElement object.

I also thought about using the DOMAttrModified event (http://help.dottoro.com/ljdchxcl.php) but it's not supported in Chrome. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Cecchi's answer is cool but it's not a true monkey patch that applies globally to all HTMLElement instances. Browsers have new capabilities since that answer.

This is tricky because `HTMLElement.prototype.innerHTML` is a setter, but I was able to get it to work like so:

```
//create a separate JS context that's clean
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

//have to append it to get access to HTMLElement
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

//grab the setter. note that __lookupSetter__ is deprecated maybe try getOwnPropertyDescriptor? anyways this works currently
let origSetter = iframe.contentWindow.HTMLElement.prototype.__lookupSetter__('innerHTML');

//mangle the global HTMLElement in this JS context
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'innerHTML', {
    set: function (val) {
        console.log('innerHTML called', val);
        // *** do whatever you want here ***
        return origSetter.call(this, val); //allow the method to be called like normal
    }
});
```

Now to test it:

```
document.createElement('div').innerHTML = '<p>oh, hey</p>';
//logs: innerHTML called <p>oh, hey</p>
```

Here's a JSBin http://jsbin.com/qikoce/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are developing for and the browser support you need (it sounds like just Chrome, and hopefully just modern Chrome), you can look into the `MutationObserver` interface (exampled borrowed and slightly modified from the [Mozilla Hacks Blog](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance):

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
    x(mutation.target);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// select the target nodes
Array.prototype.slice.apply(
    document.querySelectorAll('.nodes-to-observe')
).forEach(function(target) {
    observer.observe(target, config);
});

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

More on `MutationObserver`s can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver

This was implemented in Chrome 18 & Firefox 14.